# Python 3.8 Errorr while trying to define a range of values on a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I'm learning Python and Pandas, and I'm working on an exercise.  I'm loading in 2 csv files and merging them into one dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
# File to Load (Remember to Change These)
school_data_to_load = "Resources/schools_complete.csv"
student_data_to_load = "Resources/students_complete.csv"

# Read School and Student Data File and store into Pandas DataFrames
school_data_df = pd.read_csv(school_data_to_load)
student_data_df = pd.read_csv(student_data_to_load)

# Combine the data into a single dataset.  
school_data_complete_df = pd.merge(student_data_df, school_data_df, how="left", on=["school_name", "school_name"])
school_data_complete_df.head()
```

[image]

The output looks like the picture above.

I'm trying to:

- Calculate the percentage of students with a passing math score (70 or    greater)
- Calculate the percentage of students with a passing reading score (70    or greater)
- Calculate the percentage of students who passed math and reading (%    Overall Passing)

I'm looking to populate a new dataframe by looking at students who only got 70 or greater on their math and reading scores by using the loc command

[image]

I got this error.  I don't understand because the values in the columns should all be integers so why is it saying I'm trying to pass strings in there as well?

Comment: can you print a df.dtypes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing the values in the column. You are just comparing `"math_score" >= 70`. There's a string on the left, and an integer on the right, hence your problem.

Fix the location of your angle brackets, and you should be good to go:

```
passing_maths_total = school_data_complete_df.loc[school_data_complete_df["math score"] >= 70]
```

Pandas broadcasts the result of the `>=` comparison, so comparing the Pandas Series `school_data_complete_df["math score"]` with `70` results in a boolean Pandas Series which can be used for indexing, e.g. in `.loc`.

The colon is unnecessary because the row index comes first in `.loc` anyways.

This solution is not tested.

Comment: Thank you sir!!! I can't believe I didn't see such a tiny mistake.